# $R/J(R)$ not semisimple Artinian

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, noncommutative-algebra

> I search for a ring $R$ with Jacobson radical $J(R)$ such that $R/J(R)$ is not semisimple Artinian.

Being a finitely generated module over itself, $R$ would have infinite hollow dimension due to a fact stated by Sarath and Varadarajan to the effect that an $R$-module $M$ has finite hollow dimension only if $M/J(M)$ is a semisimple Artinian module, where $J(M)$ is the Jacobson radical of $M$. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Jacobson radical  $J(R)$ of a polynomial ring $R=D[x]$ over a commutative ring $D$ is of the form $J(R)=N[x]$ for some nilpotent ideal $N$ of $D$ (see Theorem 1 in ["Radicals of Polynomial Rings"](http://cms.math.ca/openaccess/cjm/v8/cjm1956v08.0355-0361.pdf) by Amitsur (1956) or ["Completely Primary Rings I"](http://jstor.org/stable/1969441) by Snapper (1950)). Hence $R/J(R) = (D/N)[x]$, which is not Artinian and hence not semisimple Artinian. For a concrete example, take $R=\mathbb{Z}[x]$, $R=\mathbb{Z}_n[x]$ or $R=\mathbb{Z}[t,x]/\langle t^n\rangle$, for $n>1$.

Comment: In most places I've seen it, it's been called Snapper's Theorem. I think there's a result of Amitsur for which it is a corollary, too.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I found Amitsur's paper "Radicals of Polynomial Rings" (https://cms.math.ca/openaccess/cjm/v8/cjm1956v08.0355-0361.pdf) where he proves a more general statement in Theorem 1 as the result I mentioned, which he says is due to Snapper "Completely Primary Rings I" Annals of Mathematics 1950 ( https://www.jstor.org/stable/1969441)

Answer (score 1):

For any field $F$, $R=\prod_{i=1}^\infty F$.

It has $J(R)=\{0\}$ (since it is von Neumann regular) and is clearly not Artinian.

Then if you want a version with a nonzero radical, you can take the 2 by 2 upper triangular matrix ring over this ring. Another example would be to take the subring of this matrix ring of elements with constant diagonal.

Comment: The ring above is a semisimple one. Could one find an example such that $R/J(R)$ is not semisimple? Indeed, I search for a non-semilocal ring. Thanks!

Comment: @karparvar You mean Jacobson semisimple, I guess. Sure, it's trivial to give it a nonzero radical. I edited some in.

Comment: @user26857 looks good: thanks.